# How to know the login status in Spotify

Tags: authentication, spotify

I am making an app where I need to have the user log in into their spotify account.

I would like to know how can I know if the user is already logged in or not into Spotify? 
What I am trying to do in my application is ask to log in only if I have never logged in before and take the user through the authentication process.

If I have logged in before I want to skip the part where I ask the user to log in. This would have to work also if the user has logged in, left the app for some time and came back to it, I don't want to have to require a re-login by the user. How can I get that status from Spotify ?

I appreciate any guidance with this, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's very likely that the access token has expired by the time you want to use it again, you would need to use the [Authorization Code](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization_code_flow) flow, storing the access token and refresh token of the user.

You can try making a request to an endpoint like [Get Current User's Profile](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-current-users-profile/) passing your current access token.

Should it fails, try [refreshing it](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#request-access-token-from-refresh-token). If you get an access token back, then you know the user is logged in and you have a valid token you can use. Otherwise, consider the user is not logged in.

Where to store the refresh_token and access_token is up to you. You could do it in localStorage, or even better, in a database.